# Improve SQLite Query time, two tables with foreign key

Tags: sqlite, join, time

I have two tables, RX_PACKETS_TABLE (T1), RX_EVENTS_TABLE (T2) . Both have idx. T2 also have foreign key to T1 idx.
CREATE TABLE RX_PACKETS_TABLE ( p_idx integer default 0, constraint pk_RX_PACKETS_TABLE primary key (p_idx ) )

CREATE TABLE RX_EVENTS_TABLE ( e_idx integer default 0, , p_idx integer default 0, constraint pk_RX_EVENTS_TABLE primary key (e_idx ) )

T2 rows are sorted in ascending order with respect to the idx and the foreign key. For example, T2 can store these rows:
e_idx, p_idx
    1, 1
    2, 1
    3, 2
    4, 3
    4, 4...

T2 size is approximately (T1 size) X 5.
System is running on a HW with limited resources.
I have done some experiments and fetching the last 100 joined rows when T1 has 500K rows take too much time.

I used different queries, one with JOIN operation, one with checking "in" condition on sub-query, both gave my approximately same results.
The problem for my understanding is that the SQLite engine doesn’t take advantage of the fact that T2 is sorted and don’t optimise the JOIN/test of the "IN" condition. because of that he checks every row of T2 against the JOIN/"IN" condition.

If I just fetch the last 100 rows of T2 the query time drops significantly (1ms VS 1000ms).
I thought about two solutions to my problem:
1. buffer the data and group it before writing it to the DB. this will add some delay to the data available in the DB but it's not very important.
2. Write better query and somehow take advantage of the fact that T2 is sorted by both fields but I don't know exactly how to do it.

What do you think?

Comment: What are your indexes? Actual table definitions? [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output for your queries?

Comment: Stuff like that needs to go in the question, not a comment. And if `rx_events_table` is t2 in the Q, your example data can't exist in it because it has duplicate values for the PK column...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated my question.
regarding my example data not sure why it's can't exists. first column is e_idx second is p_idx. p_idx is not unique/key in this table.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine suggested to [create an index](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/indexes.php) on the p_idx field of T2.
After doing that query time dropped significantly from around 1700ms to 1ms.